# Getrusage inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, freebsd, inline-assembly

I am trying to implement `getrusage` function into my client server program using sockets and all of this is running on FreeBSD. I want to print out processor time usage and memory usage.

I have tried to implement the following code but I am getting output `Illegal instrucion (Core dumped)`

```
int getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage){

    int errorcode;
    __asm__(
    "syscall"
    : "=a" (errorcode)
    : "a" (117), "D"  (who), "S" (usage)  //const Sysgetrusage : scno = 117
    : "memory"
    );

    if (errorcode<0) {
        printf("error");
    }
    return 1;  
}
```

**UPDATE:**  I have tried to run this but I get zero values or some random number value or negative number values. Any ideas what am I missing?

```
int getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage){

    int errorcode;
    __asm__("push $0;"
                "push %2;"
                "push %1;"
                "movl $117, %%eax;"
                "int $0x80;"
                :"=r"(errorcode)
                :"D"(who),"S"(usage)
                :"%eax"
        );

    if (errorcode<0) {
        printf("error");
    }
    return 1;

}
```

I would like to use system call `write` more likely, but it is giving me a compilation `warning: passing arg 1 of 'strlen' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

**EDIT:** (this is working code now, regarding to comment)

```
struct rusage usage;
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF,&usage);
char tmp[300];

write(i, "Memory: ", 7);
sprintf (tmp, "%ld", usage.ru_maxrss);
write(i, tmp, strlen(tmp));
write(i, "Time: ", 5);
sprintf (tmp, "%lds", usage.ru_utime.tv_sec);
write(i, tmp, strlen(tmp));
sprintf (tmp, "%ldms", usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);
write(i, tmp, strlen(tmp));
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: ru_maxrss is a long, not a string. to write it with write() you have to convert it to ascii first e.g. with `sprintf (tmp, "%ld", usage.ru_maxrss);`

Comment: @Tommylee2k does the same apply to `tv_usec` ?

Comment: I have tried as you said but still `makes pointer from integer ...` `sprintf (tmp, "%ld", usage.ru_maxrss);` `write(i, tmp, strlen(tmp));`

Comment: yes, same for tv_usec. it's a long too

Comment: @Tommylee2k okay now it seems its converted correctly but I am still getting `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` when I run this function.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Can you explain more in detail? Its first time with this stuff so ..and it compiles on 32bit freebsd server, should be fine.. my friend is running similar code on his mac and it works fine...Only thing changed is the `117` assembly code...

Comment: It may compile as 32-bit code but does it crash still with the illegal instruction? The `illegal instruction` your question originally asked about seemed awfully like the _SYSCALL_ instruction isn't available. _SYSCALL_ instruction isn't available in 32-bit programs.

Comment: I start my server, start my client and the in client mode I run this function and I get `Illegal instruction` output on server side and it crashed right away (the server). How can it be not available?

Comment: SYSCALL is a 64-bit instruction, not a 32-bit Instruction. If you are running that code that does the `syscall` on 32-bit FreeBSD it will crash because the instruction doesn't exist in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Not sure why you aren't just calling the FreeBSD `getrusage` function.

Comment: Its an assignment for school project, we were told to use inline assembly. So what you are saying is that there is no way to get it working on 32bit right? How would the `getrusage` look like without using the inline assembly in my implementation?

Comment: First off your friend who is using OS/X probably works because Apple Hardware for the last decade is usually a 64-bit processor and he is likely using 64-bit OS/X so _SYSCALL_ is available to him. In 32-bit FreeBSD code you need to use `int 0x80` rather than _SYSCALL_ instruction. Information on 32-bit `int 0x80` interface you can review this documentation: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html

Comment: The alternative is to install 64-bit FreeBSD on a machine with a 64-bit processor then your code should work.

Comment: @MichaelPetch would it be difficult for you to implement that function using `int 0x80` so I can get it to work on 32bit? Looks a bit though for me right now :/

Comment: Isn't that your assignment?

Comment: Luckily, it is :D I am gonna try but not very positive it will work :D

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have updated my question, I put some code in there but it doesnt work properly as described. Any idea?

Comment: So move `push $0` just before `int 0x80`, add `add $12, %%esp` after `int 0x80` and what about the `memory` clobber? I dont know what that is.

Comment: The `"memory"` seems not helping here cause I get zeros if I use it. If I dont use it, time adds up only for miliseconds when I call that function..

Comment: I havent. So what are u saying is that those zeroes are real values? ...cant believe it ...cant be 0 time and 0 memory used...

Comment: Have you tried for yourself? You are aware there is a `getrusage` function in the _C_ library? Just call it instead of your own code and see what it returns. I suspect you'll get the same type of value. As I said before I really am unsure why you are being tasked to rewrite a function that already exists.

Comment: There is so many things that we are supposed to rewrite but explain it to them. I guess we learn something this way, but we really dont. Anyways, it seems to be working right now so I wont touch it. thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting an `illegal instruction` error is because the [*SYSCALL*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html) instruction is only available on 64-bit FreeBSD running a 64-bit program. This is a serious issue since one of your comments suggests that your code is running on 32-bit FreeBSD.

Under normal circumstances you don't need to write your own [getrusage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getrusage&sektion=2) since it is part of the *C* library (libc) on that platform. It appears you have been tasked to do it with inline assembly.

---

### 64-bit FreeBSD and SYSCALL Instruction

There is a bit of a bug in your 64-bit code since *SYSCALL* destroys the contents of *RCX* and *R11*. Your code may work but may fail in the future especially as the program expands and you enable optimizations. The following change adds those 2 registers to the clobber list:

```
int errorcode;
    __asm__(
        "syscall"
        : "=a" (errorcode)
        : "a" (117), "D"  (who), "S" (usage)  //const Sysgetrusage : scno = 117
        : "memory", "rcx", "r11"
);
```

Using the `memory` clobber can lead to generation of inefficient code so I use it only if necessary. As you become more of an expert the need for `memory` clobber can be eliminated. I would have used a function like the following if I wasn't allowed to use the *C* library version of [getrusage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getrusage&sektion=2):

```
int getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage){

    int errorcode;
    __asm__(
        "syscall"
        : "=a"(errorcode), "=m"(*usage)
        : "0"(117), "D"(who), "S"(usage)
        : "rcx", "r11"
    );

    if (errorcode<0) {
        printf("error");
    }
    return errorcode;
}
```

This uses a memory operand as an output constraint and drops the `memory` clobber. Since the compiler knows how large a `rusage` structure and is `=m` says the output constraint modifies that memory we don't need need the `memory` clobber.

---

### 32-bit FreeBSD System Calls via Int 0x80

As mention in the comments and your updated code, to make a system call in 32-bit code in FreeBSD you have to use `int 0x80`. This is described in the [FreeBSD System Calls Convention](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html). Parameters are pushed on the stack right to left and you must allocate 4 bytes on the stack by pushing any 4 byte value onto the stack after you push the last parameter.

Your edited code has a few bugs. First you push the extra 4 bytes before the rest of the arguments. You need to push it after. You need to adjust the stack after `int 0x80` to effectively reclaim the stack space used by the arguments passed. You pushed three 4-byte values on the stack, so you need to add 12 to *ESP* after `int 0x80`.

You also need a `memory` clobber because the compiler doesn't know you have actually modified memory at all. This is because the way you have done your constraints the data in the variable `usage` gets modified but the compiler doesn't know what.

The return value of the `int 0x80` will be in *EAX* but you use the constraint `=r`. It should have been `=a` since the return value will be returned in *EAX*. Since using `=a` tells the compiler *EAX* is clobbered you don't need to list it as a clobber anymore.

The modified code could have looked like:

```
int getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage){

    int errorcode;
    __asm__("push %2;"
            "push %1;"
            "push $0;"
            "movl $117, %%eax;"
            "int $0x80;"
            "add $12, %%esp"
            :"=a"(errorcode)
            :"D"(who),"S"(usage)
            :"memory"
            );

    if (errorcode<0) {
        printf("error");
    }
    return errorcode;
}
```

Another way one could have written this with more advanced techniques is:

```
int getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage){

    int errorcode;
    __asm__("push %[usage]\n\t"
            "push %[who]\n\t"
            "push %%eax\n\t"
            "int $0x80\n\t"
            "add $12, %%esp"
            :"=a"(errorcode), "=m"(*usage)
            :"0"(117), [who]"ri"(who), [usage]"r"(usage)
            :"cc" /* Don't need this with x86 inline asm but use for clarity */
        );

    if (errorcode<0) {
        printf("error");
    }
    return errorcode;
}
```

This uses a label (`usage` and `who`) to identify each parameter rather than using numerical positions like `%3`, `%4` etc. This makes the inline assembly easier to follow. Since any 4-byte value can be pushed onto the stack just before `int 0x80` we can save a few bytes by simply pushing the contents of any register. In this case I used `%%eax`. This uses `=m` constraint like I did in the 64-bit example.

More information on extended inline assembler can be found in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).